# Problematic line breaks in bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I hope this is not a duplicate, haven't found it by myself so.... 
I have this question: when I do:
`echo "some very long text"`

it breaks some words, like if I use the word "elephant" close to the end of the line, it makes it to "eleph\nant". But when I receive an error message or something it always keeps whole words together. Am I missing something? How to set up this formatting?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In what way is it problematic?

Comment: I don't want the shell to tear my words apart but to keep whole words together.  Some programs always output nice formatted text, but my scripts have these words over two lines... Any ideas?

Comment: If it bothers you you could always `fold` output to the current width of the terminal `... | fold -s -w $COLUMNS`

Answer (score 1):

I fear that you don't want to do this, but this script should make something that you would like:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$(cat)
line=""
max=$1

for word in $input; do
  if (( (${#line} + ${#word} + 1) > max )); then
    echo "$line"
    line=""
  fi

  line+="$word"
  line+=" "
done

echo $line
```

**Usage:** `cat text_file.txt | bash the_script.sh $COLUMNS`

Comment: fold works perfectly for now... as described in the comments. But thanks for your post :)

Comment: @IcyIcyIce: You're welcome!